# C# IComparable IComparer with additional Param

Tags: c#

How can I implement `IComparer`

`int CompareTo(object obj)`

with an additional parameter, like

`int CompareTo(object obj, Dictionary<int, int> preferences)`

preferences is a dictionary with `Id` and `NumberOfClicks<int, int>`

What I want is compare contents which have categoryId by the number of clicks in the dictionary,

Example Cat 1 has 3 clicks, Cat 2 has 6 clicks.

Sort by comparing 
`preferences[this.CategoryId].value > preferences[object.CategoryId].value`

So they are sorted by category, but in relation to the `Dictionary`.

Comment: The signature that you show is from `IComparable`, not `IComparer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass extra arguments to `IComparer`'s `Compare` method, because method signature must match the signature in the interface.

What you can do is to construct an instance of `IComparer` with the extra parameter, store it in the instance, and use inside `CompareTo` as needed:

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<object> {
    private readonly IDictionary<int, int> preferences;
    public MyComparer(IDictionary<int, int> preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }
    public int Compare(object a, object b) {
        ... // Perform the comparison with preferences in scope
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate comparer class that implements `IComparer<T>`, rather than having the type itself implement `IComparable`, and have it accept the `Dictionary` in its constructor.  That comparer can then use the dictionary when it compares instances of your object.